# How to use jquery animation to make a list of items and details of a selected item

Tags: jquery

I am building a customer portal for our clients. I hired a web designer to give me some aesthetic advice on the pages.  He gave me the following 2 images.  I am trying to mimic what he gave me.  On the main page is a list of tickets our customer has (1st image).  If you click on any of the tickets, the list of tickets slides to the left, and shows less data than the main page(2nd image), but calls details of the ticket you clicked on.  I don't even know where to begin to determine what I need to use to make this work.  What Jquery effects should i use?  Should I just manipulate the data I have, or make a new call to the db to make the tickets detail page?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add the code with jsfiddle, so we can help you.

Comment: "I don't even know where to begin......." -- me    :)
These are images he gave me. I dont have any code

Comment: oh sorry. Try to start with some tables, give them titles and some fake data. For the second part, you can use https://nathancahill.github.io/Split.js/. Good luck!

Comment: this looks like what Im looking for. Thank you